# jquery ui checkbox performance issue

Tags: javascript, performance, jquery-ui, checkbox

I've got a backbone application in which I render a big table of tree nodes (each table line represents one node). Nodes have jquery ui checkbox. The tree is quite big (around one thousand elements rendered). My page was rendering quite slow and I've found out that the line:

```
this.$el.html(tpl({
    nodesList: nodes
}));
this.$el.find(':checkbox').checkbox();
```

`nodes` is just a huge list of nodes that are used with one handlebars template (loop over nodes).

The last (checkbox) line takes more than 2 seconds. Is there any well-known workaround for rendering lots of jquery ui checkboxes? Or is there anything else I can do to speed it up?

Comment: can you pls share your code or put it on JSFiddle

Comment: @BhushanKawadkar: I can't paste entire code (it's not mine) and it's difficult to get anything interesting from the code. The case is to make 1 thousand of simple checkboxes into jquery ui checkboxes. Is it ok that it takes more than 2 seconds?

Comment: i think here 'find' in $el.find(':checkbox') is taking time. what is $el here?

Comment: this is a backbone view attribute. Backbone view is an object. El is it's element and $el is its jquery handler and it has all jquery api available.

Comment: i tried creating 1000 checkboxes, it goes well. but when i tried creating and then selecting or checking all created checkboxes, then it is taking around 2 seconds time at my side too. so when will you perform any action on checkboxes, it is taking time to complete it.